# Xamarin Forms Out Of Memory Android

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, out-of-memory, xamarin.forms

I'm working with a Xamarin Forms app that uses a lot of button with images.
So after some time of navigation my android app crash, beacuse of out of memory problem.
How can I handle this problem?

Answer (score 2):

You need to be very careful when dealing with images:

> Before an image is displayed on the screen, it has to be loaded into
> the memory.
>
> Let’s assume you have a brand new device with full HD screen and 12 MP
> camera. The picture you just took is 4000x3000 pixels large and the
> total memory needed to display it is: 4 bytes * 4000 * 3000 = 48 MB for a single image!

What you need to do is:

- Measure the view you’re showing your images in.
- Scale / crop the large image accordingly.
- Show only what can be displayed.

Above info from the below resources:

1. Read More : [Here](https://www.toptal.com/android/top-10-most-common-android-development-mistakes) - Point #8.
2. Read More: [Android](https://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html) (Walk-through on how to resize and crop images)

You can follow the same approaches using C# to resize the large images and display them efficiently.